# Killing process in docker leave kernel thread

Tags: python, docker

I'm experimenting with Docker and solved most of my issues but can't budge with this one.

I Have a python app that periodically turn on vpn ( via openvpn client ) inside the docker, do some stuff and than will do

```
os.system("pkill -f openvpn")
#os.system("killall openvpn")
```

I have tried both and both work fine on just stand alone system, but in docker they leave behind Kernel threads(?) every time the openvpn demon is killed.

Openvpn client is called like this inside the script:

```
os.system("/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --config " + config_file)
```

But every time its killed ps get one more [openvpn]

```
/app # ps auxf
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:01 python app.py
    9 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   10 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   16 root      0:00 sh
   41 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   42 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   57 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   58 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   75 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   76 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   89 root      0:00 [openvpn]
   90 root      0:00 [openvpn]
  106 root      0:00 [openvpn]
  107 root      0:00 [openvpn]
  123 root      0:00 [openvpn]
  124 root      0:00 [openvpn]
  137 root      0:00 [openvpn]
  138 root      0:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --config /etc/openvpn/VPNarea/Poland-Warsaw.ovpn
  145 root      0:00 ps auxf
```

Why is this happening ? Or how to prevent it ?

Comment: Seems like the issue is with adoption, since I run the python directly in docker via ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"], but I use this to catch SIGTERM and exit cleanly ... if I used sh/bash as pid1 than the process would clean up ( I think ) but SIGTEM is not than send further... this sux a little :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're leaking zombie processes.

When you run inside a Docker container, your process has the process ID 1.  That means if something inside the container gets killed, and its parent is gone (for example, because it's done a double-fork to become a daemon process), your process becomes its new parent, and you are responsible for **wait**(2)ing for it.  When you don't do this, you get zombie processes like this.

One immediate answer could be to [`os.waitpid(-1, 0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitpid) after you issue the "kill".  That will cause you to wait for the next thing that exits and do the required cleanup.

It'd be cleaner to not try to do this cleanup so indirectly, though.  Instead of launching the subprocess as a daemon and trying to clean up after it later, you can use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to create a process.  You can have the process run "in the foreground", but not block on it completing in your Python process.  That would look something like

```py
vpn = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/sbin/openvpn", "--config", config_file])
...
vpn.kill()
vpn.wait()
```

If you can split things out so that these two items run in separate containers that would be better still; then you can avoid this management issue.

(...what happens when `config_file = "/dev/null; cat /etc/shadow"`?  Try to avoid using the string-form commands like `os.system()` if at all possible.)

Comment: You are correct, I will have to rewrite the app a little, I'll try with subprocess that should be the easiest way to rework it. And later look into putting vpn in separate container ( but that would complicate the app a lot )

Comment: It works perfectly with subprocess, it solved my last headache for the app, thanks so much !